# Creating a new log window in Python

Tags: python

So I want to see a separate window to print certain things from my code

for example:

```
print('hello world') #this will be on the normal python window

more code

printtowindow('this is not the python window') #I think you understood
```

I am on windows 10 (64 bits), python 3.8.1

Answer (score -1):

Use sockets, I have a gist [here.](https://gist.github.com/Krewn/be2115d413d2e7252feebdd6963a10a6) https://gist.github.com/Krewn/be2115d413d2e7252feebdd6963a10a6

Comment: I don't understand, I just want a window to print text I wrote in my code on my computer, just like python idle